# angular full calendar update UI after adding an event

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm new to angular. I'm trying to build an event app with FullCalendar and Angular Material
I am able to get and save the events from/in the database
The problem I'm facing is that the UI is not updating after I do a save or a delete
I need to  refresh the page to be able to see the new event

my calendar component:

```js
 events = []
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions
  eventToAdd: Event = new Event()
  eventId: string

  constructor (
    private calendarService: CalendarService,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.calendarService.getEvents().subscribe(data => {
      this.events = data
      if(this.events && this.events.length) {
        this.calendarOptions = {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
          dateClick: this.openDialog.bind(this),
          events: this.events,
          eventClick : (event) => {
            this.eventId = event.event._def.extendedProps._id
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }

  openDialog(arg) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EventDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        date: arg.dateStr,
        value: 56,
        title: "BURNEDBODY",
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(event => {
      this.calendarService.createEvent(event).subscribe(event => {
        this.calendarService.getEvents().subscribe(events => {
          this.events = events
        })
      })
    })
  }
}
```

my dialog component :

```js
export class EventDialogComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EventDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) { }

    
  onNoClick(): void {
  this.dialogRef.close();
 }
}
```

calendar html :

```html
<div class="calendar">
    <full-calendar 
        [options]="calendarOptions">
    </full-calendar>
</div>
```

dialog html :

```js
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <p>Add event :</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: Hi, Can you create a minimum reproducible example on stackblitz.com